# How to show that $ \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^a} \mathrm{d}x$ is not integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I wonder how to show that $$ \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^a} \mathrm{d}x$$ is not Lebesgue-integrable, where $a<1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is Lebesgue integrable (for $a > 0$). The integrand should be around $\frac{1}{x^{a+1}}$.

Comment: well what have you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}{x^a}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\sin(x)\,x^{a-2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x)}x\,x^{a-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: **Happy New Year !**

Comment: It makes sense, thank you!